# How to use weighting in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I don't understand how weighting works in the `dplyr::sample_n` function. I have a list of very small numbers (ranging from 0.1020457 to 0.1789028) and I need to weight my sampling so that I get some on the lower end, upper end and in the middle. But since the numbers are so similar, I'm not sure how to do it. I also don't want to restrict my sampling to a certain range either (e.g. numbers > 0.16), i just want those far more likely to be sampled.

I can make the range larger (-1.552115 to 2.008253) but that means scaling by data, and I can't weight with negative numbers. I have to do things like abs(numbers - maximum). Heres an example of what I'm doing:

```
sample_n(data.frame(scaledMeasurement$V1), 4, 
         replace = FALSE, 
         weight = abs((scaledMeasurement $V1) - max(scaledMeasurement $V1)))
```

Heres a section of my data:

```
Measurement ID    
0.8022473 1
1.6991193 2
0.7262765 3
0.3903775 4
-1.5521155 5
-0.7821887 6
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thanks for adding an example of what you're attempting--it's always good to see the code. However, as Ronak indicated, it's helpful to provide sample data. Plus it's easier for you since we can then use your specified variables in the code instead of random ones for placeholders.

Comment: I don't really understand how you want to sample from your numbers. My understanding is that you have an unknown distribution of numbers, and you want to sample, ensuring that you sample more heavily from the tails than you would by sampling uniformly. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get a sample that contains some on the low end, some near the median, and some on the end, it's far easier to avoid weights and just work with `group_by` + `sample_n`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df = tibble(my_nums = runif(10,0.1020457,0.1789028))    
df %>% 
  mutate(quantile = case_when(
    my_nums <= quantile(my_nums, probs = c(0.33)) ~ "a",
    my_nums <= quantile(my_nums, probs = c(0.67)) ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ "c"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(quantile) %>% 
  sample_n(2)
```

Produces:

```
    my_nums quantile
    <dbl> <chr>   
1   0.105 a       
2   0.105 a       
3   0.151 b       
4   0.124 b       
5   0.173 c       
6   0.172 c
```

However, if you wanted to use weights, `sample_n` requires that the weights be the same length as the vector that's being sampled and also that the sum of the weights is equal to 1. You could add a weight column based on a subdivision of your groups (as I show above quantiles), grouping by that, generating a random number between one and length, ungrouping, and then dividing the values in that column by its sum. Like so:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(quantile = case_when(
    my_nums <= quantile(my_nums, probs = c(0.33)) ~ "a",
    my_nums <= quantile(my_nums, probs = c(0.67)) ~ "b",
    TRUE ~ "c"
  )) %>% 
  group_by(quantile) %>% 
  mutate(weight = sample(seq(1,length(my_nums)),length(my_nums))) %>% 
  ungroup %>%  arrange(quantile) %>% 
  mutate(weight = weight / sum(weight)) %>% 
  sample_n(6, weight = weight)
```